# Angular 7 - How to show loader until *ngFor loads the data?

Tags: angular, angular7

How to show loader until *ngFor loads the data?

```html
<mat-list role="list" *ngFor="let item of channel.channel; let i=index">
    <mat-list-item role="listitem">{{i + 1}}. {{item}}</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

It is taking the long time to load, how to show loader until data load gets complete?

Comment: Can you show how you load the data?

Answer (score 2):

You could add `*ngIf="channel.channel"` to the `mat-list` and use a `mat-spinner` underneath with `*ngIf="!channel.channel"`

For example:

```
<mat-list role="list" *ngIf="channel.channel" *ngFor="let item of channel.channel; let i=index">
     <mat-list-item role="listitem">{{i + 1}}. {{item}}</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>

<mat-spinner *ngIf="!channel.channel"></mat-spinner>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have a boolean variable defined in your component level as,

**`showLoader : boolean = true;`**

and then, once you get your data, assin the value to false.

**`this.showLoader = false;`**

you can use *ngIf on your  template you check whether the data is loaded,

```
<mat-list role="list" *ngIf="!showLoader" *ngFor="let item of channel.channel; let i=index">
     <mat-list-item role="listitem">{{i + 1}}. {{item}}</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>

<mat-spinner *ngIf="showLoader"></mat-spinner>
```